# How to use a variable which contains css class in it to with document.queryselector()?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am having dynamically generating `Div` which contain a different bootstrap class for each and every generated `Div`. Now I need to get that particular `Div` based on its class?
Am trying with this `document.querySelector("."+Classvariable)`;
but its always returning null.

Comment: you mean getElementsByClassName not querySelector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery

```
var Classvariable = 'class';

$('.'+Classvariable).css({'color':'red'});
```

Comment: my class name is not the original CSS class. but it is a string, I need to append some values to that DIV. and I have only unique is that class name

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Am using a progress bar its value is 0 initially and when file uploaded 1% then my server gives response that particular file was uploaded 1% and I need to append this response to only that particular div which is acting as a progress-bar

Comment: add a class to that progress bar, why is it that complicated?

Comment: as am trying to use document.querySelector(); this function was not allowing to pass a variable as argument.

Comment: querySelector searches by selector not class names use getElementsByClassName  to query the dom by classes

Comment: what do you mean by brief?describe what getElementsByClassName does?

Comment: not getElementsByClassName, i need about document.querySelector. why am unable to pass a variable to it. does it has any predefined selectors

Comment: read the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector